Using present perfect for routines
Can we use present perfect in the present with "when" if is it a routine and not a single action?

"Every morning I have made sandwiches when kids wake up"

— meaning they are already done before kids get up
That seems valid to me and I saw some similar examples here: Present perfect for daily routine: Every day "by the time" and on Quora,  John R.Yamamoto-Wilson's answer makes me believe it is correct. I just want to make sure it works?

You can, but it would be more idiomatic to say something like I've already made the sandwiches by the time the kids wake up.

No, marta. Use the simple present for that: "Every morning I make sandwiches when kids wake up".  routines generally take the present simple.

That sentence by Yamamoto-Wilson is NOT like yours. By the time the kids wake up, I have made sandwiches.

I have added a P.S. to my answer, addressing Yamamoto-Wilson's examples.

The idiomatic choice for ongoing routines that you are still following is simple present:

Every morning I make sandwiches before the kids wake up.

But let's say it was a summer job at a camp for kids, and now it is autumn, and you are back at school:

Every morning I made sandwiches before the kids woke up.

If your question is about whether the perfect can be used to imply a sequence of events in the past, there are clearer choices than when that cooperate with the perfect to express that meaning, and you would need to use the past perfect not the present perfect:

Every morning,  by the time the kids woke up, I had made all the sandwiches.
Every morning, before the kids woke up, I had made all the sandwiches.

It is not impossible to use when there instead of by the time or before, but it is fragile and would be very low on the list of possibilities:

Every morning, when the kids woke up, I had made all the sandwiches.

It might work better in a narrative where there is a supporting statement:

At the camp, I woke up very early before any of the kids in order to do my assigned tasks.  When the kids woke up, I would have made  all the sandwiches for lunch.

But even there "by the time" would be more suitable than "when".
P.S.   The present perfect is not incompatible with routines. Yamamoto-Wilson gives valid examples. But the present perfect doesn't express the routine per se; it expresses a circumstance that attends the routine; the routine is expressed with the simple present:

I have usually done the work before the boss arrives each day.
Before the boss arrives each day, I have usually done the work.


that's not what I'm asking about. It is clear to me that in the past it is okay to use past perfect. I am asking about a present routine and using present perfect. for instance it is okay to write " When she got home I had made dinner". Can we dp the same in the present "Alwasy when she gets home I have made dinner" meaning it is already ready

@marta  When she gets home, I have made dinner. is not impossible. but when is fragile as it is not as clear as other phrases and is far less likely to be used.  By the time she gets home, I have dinner ready. or Before she gets home, I have made dinner.

what about "By the time she gets home, I have made dinner" with present perfect?

@marta Yes, By the time she gets home, I have made dinner. is OK. But "have made dinner" could fit situations where dinner has been sitting in the oven drying out as you wait for her to get home. If the timing is perfect you'd say, "I have dinner ready".

@marta My summation of the point behind TimR's answer is "We don't usually use perfect when we don't have to." Simple is, well, simpler. There are plenty of times that you could use a perfect tense, and maybe it wouldn't be wrong, but if a simple tense serves your needs just as well, it's more often chosen.

@marta Please stop changing your question.

@Lambie I'm not doing anything. Other members are changing my post.

It doesn’t sound correct.
It leaves it open to misinterpretation. For example: “I have made food when the kids wake?” No,
you would say “when she gets home” ( future)
I will have (future) made dinner.” Meaning when event one happens, in the future, the other thing will (in the future) be done already (at that time).
When he is home, I make dinner. (If you do it when they are there)
When the kids get up, I will have made their lunch already.
If you say: when the kids wake up, I have made their lunch, it ties the lunch making to the waking in the wrong way. I’m that sentence, it sounds like something you did in the rather remote past. It's not how native speakers would say it.
“When my husband is home, I have made dinner.”- no.
“When my husband arrives home, I will have made dinner. “ Ok
“When my kids wake, I will have made their lunches.”. Ok
You need the “will” because it’s hypothetical, describing a situation,and making the person’s position in time , relative to your action, the reference as a point in time.
Using have alone: “I have worked there before.” an unspecified time, in the past. You use “have”.
“I have made a sandwich.” A while ago, you made a sandwich.
This is often used to indicate experience, or minimal competence.
“You don’t need to tell me how to make a campfire. I have gone camping before, Susan!”
“I have fixed a flat tire before.”
“I have worked in communications.”

You're confused about how the perfect works. You'd use the perfect when talking about a routine if you doing the routine was something that happened in the past, up until now, but you no longer follow the routine: "Every morning I have made sandwiches for my husband, but now he's working from home so I don't have to."
You don't use the perfect just because one thing happened before something else as part of the routine. If you are still making sandwiches then say "Every morning I make sandwiches before the kids wake up".

please comment on John R.Yamamoto-Wilson's answer
